# OnItemClickListener() not working with List Adapter

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

I am fetching data in to list adapter through calling a function named `getAllDishes()`. Now I want to add `OnItemClickListener()` on list when I click on a particular item, it opens another activity and pass the id of selected item. I am new to android. All suggestions are welcome.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity   {

 private DishOperation dishDBoperation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button   btListe;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dishDBoperation = new DishOperation(this);
        dishDBoperation.open();

        List values = dishDBoperation.getAllDishes();


        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

//This is what i tried
 OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
         }
```

Comment: at first remove `finish();`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya problem is with OnItemClickListener this gives a bracket error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way , You can use this

```
    ListView listView = getListView();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // Do your Staff Here 

          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Or

You can use

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

After **`setListAdapter(adapter);`**

Comment: How can i pass selected item id from database to new page i.e `results` where i can show some more information taking that id as key

Comment: You can use `Bundle` or `sharedpref`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ItemClickListener` to list view :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, add this line: `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);`

like this:

```
OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
         }
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually **set** the click listener to the `ListView`. In your onCreate, after the call to `setAdapter(adapter)`, call `getListView().setOnItemClickListener(listener);`